# Learning recursion.. I'm trying to permutate a string recursively in Python3, but my code is generating duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This is a function that permutates a string recursively. To be honest I'm not quite sure how it works but I'm trying to figure it out. It runs just fine, but the list it returns contains a lot of duplicates. How can I prevent duplicates from being created?

```
def permutateRecursion(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return [string]
    else:
        permutation = []
        for x in permutateRecursion(string[:-1]):
            for y in range(len(string) + 1):
                permutation.append(x[:y] + string[-1] + x[y:])
        return permutation
```

Comment: What you're doing isn't a full permutation, but the reason you have a repeat at the end is you're adding 1 to the range, should just be `range(len(string))`

Comment: I just tried it out, and it worked! Just curious though, how is it not a full permutation? I just tested it out with "ABCD" and the output displayed every combination.

Comment: When I try it with `'ABCD'` I get `['DCBA', 'CDBA', 'CBDA', 'CBAD']`, that's absolutely not every permutation, that's just the character `'D'` shifted throught the reversed string.

Comment: Huh, that's strange. This is my output http://imgur.com/a/YGppb

Comment: I also get the correct output, after removing the +1.